# Swift - How to get the last modification date of file via HTTP on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing iOS mobile app.

In certain task I have to implement mechanism which should keep in sync local file in iOS app sandbox and remote file on server. File can be changed on the server and iOS app should download that new file version from the server and overwrite local version of file on the phone by new file from the server.

Initially I was though to make download that file everytime app started. But such approach will do worthless work in case if the file didn't change on the server. File is too large and it is too costly to download it too often.

So I decide to check first, is the file changed on the server or not. In that case mechanism should compare last modification date of local file with remote file to determine, if download is required or not.

Interface of such function should be something like this:

```
func getFileLastModifiedDate(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ modificatinDate: String?) -> ()) {
    let lastModified = <retrieve lastModified from file by URL>
    completion(lastModified)
}
```

Is there way to get last modification date of remote file via `HTTP` WITHOUT downloading it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it that way:

**Swift 5.x** solution:

```
func getFileLastModifiedDate(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ modificatinDate: String?) -> ()) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        let headers = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.allHeaderFields
        var lastModified: String?
        if let headers = headers {
            lastModified = headers["Last-Modified"] as? String
        }
        NSLog("Last-Modified Date: %@", lastModified ?? "")

        // cast to Date
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
        if let lastModified = lastModified {
            if let lastModifiedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: lastModified) {
                print(lastModifiedDate)
            }
        }

        completion(lastModified)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: This really cool. Is it possible to get the day and month as an integer from this?

Comment: @JPJerry5 yes, of course. You can cast it to Date and get any part you need. Answer updated, check for details.             let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
            if let lastModified = lastModified {
                if let lastModifiedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: lastModified) {
                    print(lastModifiedDate)
                }
            }

Comment: Hello, can you tell me how it work ?
I want to check date creation from http://..../file.zip

Comment: let srcURL : URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "your path"); getFileLastModifiedDate(url: srcURL, completion: { _ in })